# Source file compile error

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

```
...
Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
...
```

In truffle-config i have set

```
...
  compilers: {
    solc: {
       version: "0.5.16",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
      // docker: true,        // Use "0.5.1" you've installed locally with docker (default: false)
      // settings: {          // See the solidity docs for advice about optimization and evmVersion
      //  optimizer: {
      //    enabled: false,
      //    runs: 200
      //  },
      //  evmVersion: "byzantium"
      // }
    }
  },
...
```

But I'm getting error when I run truffle test.

```
  TestFirst
    1) testAge
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (25s)
  1 failing

  1) TestFirst
       testAge:
     Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
      at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Users\92311\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\testing\SolidityTest.js:92:1)
      at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
...
```

Comment: The error at the beginning is not connected to the last error. The last error simply means that the test reverts for some reason.

Comment: Try using latest compiler version

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

compilers: {
solc: {
version: "0.8.2",

...